# bloco de spans não que se ajustar ao tamanho!

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    function animaTextos(){
     var interval;
     var contador = 1;
     var funcao = function() {
      var corrente = $('div.slider ul.slide li').length;
      if(corrente == contador) {
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo');
       $('div.slider ul.slide li').first().addClass('tituloAtivo');
       contador = 1;
      } else {
       contador++;
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo').next().addClass('tituloAtivo');
   
      }
     };
     interval = setInterval(funcao, 1000);
    }
   
    animaTextos();
   }); 


      window.onload = function() {
    
         var indexAtiva = 0;
   
         const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');
      
         function slider(s) {
      
            for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
               lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
            }
      
            // aqui irá tratar o clique no "Anterior".
            // É preciso tratar de 3 formas diferentes
            // dependendo do valor de indexAtiva.
            // Veja que o valor de indexAtiva, em cada caso,
            // irá receber o valor do índice ativado
            if(s){
               // significa que o próximo a mostrar será o
               // slide de índice 1, então está sendo exibido o 0.
               // neste caso eu ativo o último da array
               if(indexAtiva == 1){
                  lis[lis.length-1].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-1;
                  
               // aqui diz que está exibindo o último,
               // logo próximo será o primeiro (índice 0).
               // Então eu ativo o antepenúltimo da array
               }else if(indexAtiva == 0){
                  lis[lis.length-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-2;
                  
                // aqui é quando não for nenhum dos casos anteriores.
                // Eu diminuo 2 índices porque mais a frente será
                // incrementado com +1
               }else{
                  lis[indexAtiva-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva -= 2;
               }
            }else{
               // aqui é quando for clicado o botão "próximo"
               // ou quando nenhum botão for clicado
               lis[indexAtiva].className = 'ativa';
            }
      
            indexAtiva = indexAtiva + 1 == lis.length ? 0 : indexAtiva+=1;
      
            tempo = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
         }
      
         slider();
         
         var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
         var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
         var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
         var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
         
         anterior.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider(true);
         }
         
         proximo.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider();
         }
      
      }
```

```css
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
          outline: 0;
      }
      body {
          width: 100vw;
      }
      ul {
          list-style: none;
      }
   .setaDireita {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/direita.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
   .setaEsquerda {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/esquerda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
      .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
       @keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
      @keyframes slider {
       0% {
       transform: scale(1);
      }
       100% {
       transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      }
      div.slider {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide {
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li {
          display: none;
      }
      .ativa {
          display: block !important;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li img {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          animation: slider 1s linear, fade 1s linear;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li span {
          position: absolute;
          width: 200px;
          left: calc(50% - 100px);
          line-height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          text-align: center;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          z-index: 2;
    
    opacity                            : 0;
    top                                : 85px;   
    -webkit-transition                 : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
      }
   
   div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo span {
    font-size:30px;
    opacity                            : 1;
    top                                : 0;
    -webkit-transition                 : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
   }
   
      div.slider nav {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      div.slider nav button {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      div.slider nav button.anterior {
          left: 10%;
      }
      div.slider nav button.proximo {
          right: 10%;
      }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">

      <ul class="slide">

        <li class="ativa tituloAtivo"> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 1</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 2</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 3</span> 
         </li>

      </ul>

      <nav>
        <button class="anterior setaEsquerda"></button>
        <button class="proximo setaDireita"></button>
      </nav>

    </div>
```

O objetivo é fazer como que os textos que estão aparecendo apareça sobre a barra de navegação. Isto é, em cima dela porém com a mesma altura e que também o efeito de subir e descer do texto ocorra levemente dentro dessa altura.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize breakpoints para ajustar a cada resolução de tela.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animaTextos(){
     var interval;
     var contador = 1;
     var funcao = function() {
      var corrente = $('div.slider ul.slide li').length;
      if(corrente == contador) {
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo');
       $('div.slider ul.slide li').first().addClass('tituloAtivo');
       contador = 1;
      } else {
       contador++;
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo').next().addClass('tituloAtivo');
   
      }
     };
     interval = setInterval(funcao, 1000);
    }
   
    animaTextos();
   }); 


      window.onload = function() {
    
         var indexAtiva = 0;
   
         const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');
      
         function slider(s) {
      
            for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
               lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
            }
      
            // aqui irá tratar o clique no "Anterior".
            // É preciso tratar de 3 formas diferentes
            // dependendo do valor de indexAtiva.
            // Veja que o valor de indexAtiva, em cada caso,
            // irá receber o valor do índice ativado
            if(s){
               // significa que o próximo a mostrar será o
               // slide de índice 1, então está sendo exibido o 0.
               // neste caso eu ativo o último da array
               if(indexAtiva == 1){
                  lis[lis.length-1].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-1;
                  
               // aqui diz que está exibindo o último,
               // logo próximo será o primeiro (índice 0).
               // Então eu ativo o antepenúltimo da array
               }else if(indexAtiva == 0){
                  lis[lis.length-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-2;
                  
                // aqui é quando não for nenhum dos casos anteriores.
                // Eu diminuo 2 índices porque mais a frente será
                // incrementado com +1
               }else{
                  lis[indexAtiva-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva -= 2;
               }
            }else{
               // aqui é quando for clicado o botão "próximo"
               // ou quando nenhum botão for clicado
               lis[indexAtiva].className = 'ativa';
            }
      
            indexAtiva = indexAtiva + 1 == lis.length ? 0 : indexAtiva+=1;
      
            tempo = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
         }
      
         slider();
         
         var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
         var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
         var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
         var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
         
         anterior.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider(true);
         }
         
         proximo.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider();
         }
      
      }
```

```css
* {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
          outline: 0;
      }
      body {
          width: 100vw;
      }
      ul {
          list-style: none;
      }
   .setaDireita {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/direita.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
   .setaEsquerda {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/esquerda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
      .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
       @keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
      @keyframes slider {
       0% {
       transform: scale(1);
      }
       100% {
       transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      }
      div.slider {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide {
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li {
          display: none;
      }
      .ativa {
          display: block !important;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li img {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          animation: slider 1s linear, fade 1s linear;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li span {
          position: absolute;
          width: 200px;
          left: calc(50% - 100px);
          line-height: 40px;
          margin-top: 29%;
          text-align: center;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          z-index: 2;
    
    opacity                            : 0;
    top                                : 5px;   
    -webkit-transition                 : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
      }
   
   div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo span {
    font-size:30px;
    opacity                            : 1;
    top                                : 0;
    -webkit-transition                 : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
   }
   
      div.slider nav {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      div.slider nav button {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      div.slider nav button.anterior {
          left: 10%;
      }
      div.slider nav button.proximo {
          right: 10%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">

      <ul class="slide">

        <li class="ativa tituloAtivo"> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 1</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 2</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 3</span> 
         </li>

      </ul>

      <nav>
        <button class="anterior setaEsquerda"></button>
        <button class="proximo setaDireita"></button>
      </nav>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve fazer com que os spans tenha a mesma altura da `nav`, que é fixa em `40px`. Depois ajustar o `bottom` inicial para `-40px` e quando receber a classe que faz a animação, para `0`.

Veja os comentários no CSS para ver o que foi alterado e ajustado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animaTextos(){
     var interval;
     var contador = 1;
     var funcao = function() {
      var corrente = $('div.slider ul.slide li').length;
      if(corrente == contador) {
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo');
       $('div.slider ul.slide li').first().addClass('tituloAtivo');
       contador = 1;
      } else {
       contador++;
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo').next().addClass('tituloAtivo');
   
      }
     };
     interval = setInterval(funcao, 1000);
    }
   
    animaTextos();
   }); 


      window.onload = function() {
    
         var indexAtiva = 0;
   
         const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');
      
         function slider(s) {
      
            for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
               lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
            }
      
            // aqui irá tratar o clique no "Anterior".
            // É preciso tratar de 3 formas diferentes
            // dependendo do valor de indexAtiva.
            // Veja que o valor de indexAtiva, em cada caso,
            // irá receber o valor do índice ativado
            if(s){
               // significa que o próximo a mostrar será o
               // slide de índice 1, então está sendo exibido o 0.
               // neste caso eu ativo o último da array
               if(indexAtiva == 1){
                  lis[lis.length-1].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-1;
                  
               // aqui diz que está exibindo o último,
               // logo próximo será o primeiro (índice 0).
               // Então eu ativo o antepenúltimo da array
               }else if(indexAtiva == 0){
                  lis[lis.length-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-2;
                  
                // aqui é quando não for nenhum dos casos anteriores.
                // Eu diminuo 2 índices porque mais a frente será
                // incrementado com +1
               }else{
                  lis[indexAtiva-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva -= 2;
               }
            }else{
               // aqui é quando for clicado o botão "próximo"
               // ou quando nenhum botão for clicado
               lis[indexAtiva].className = 'ativa';
            }
      
            indexAtiva = indexAtiva + 1 == lis.length ? 0 : indexAtiva+=1;
      
            tempo = setTimeout(slider, 3000);
         }
      
         slider();
         
         var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
         var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
         var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
         var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
         
         anterior.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider(true);
         }
         
         proximo.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider();
         }
      
      }
```

```css
* {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
          outline: 0;
      }
      body {
          width: 100vw;
      }
      ul {
          list-style: none;
      }
   .setaDireita {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/direita.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
   .setaEsquerda {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/esquerda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
      .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
       @keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
      @keyframes slider {
       0% {
       transform: scale(1);
      }
       100% {
       transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      }
      div.slider {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide {
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li {
          display: none;
      }
      .ativa {
          display: block !important;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li img {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          animation: slider 1s linear, fade 1s linear;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li span {
         height: 40px; /* adicionado */
          position: absolute;
          width: 200px;
          left: calc(50% - 100px);
          line-height: 40px;
          bottom: -40px !important; /* ajustado */
          text-align: center;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          z-index: 2;
    
    opacity                            : 1;
    /* top                                : 85px; removido */
    -webkit-transition                 : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
      }
   
   div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo span {
    font-size:30px;
    opacity                            : 1;
    /*top                                : 0; removido */
        bottom: 0 !important;/* adicionado */
    -webkit-transition                 : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition                    : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition                      : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition                         : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function         : ease;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function : ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
   }
   
      div.slider nav {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      div.slider nav button {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      div.slider nav button.anterior {
          left: 10%;
      }
      div.slider nav button.proximo {
          right: 10%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">

      <ul class="slide">

        <li class="ativa tituloAtivo"> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 1</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 2</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 3</span> 
         </li>

      </ul>

      <nav>
        <button class="anterior setaEsquerda"></button>
        <button class="proximo setaDireita"></button>
      </nav>

    </div>
```

Comment: Desta forma não dá porque se o usuário clicar nas setas, para direita e para a esquerda, o texto não vai mais condizer com a imagem. No caso, o texto é uma descrição da imagem entende?

Comment: Mas a função que anima o texto é independente da que muda os slides. Teria que fazer uma chamada para a função do texto quando um botão for clicado. Nem no seu código original isso está funcionando direito. Apenas propus o que pediu a pergunta, que é ajustar os spans dentro da nav.

Comment: Pronto, não mexi em nada do JS, apenas no CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, vou dar a minha resposta.

Também pode ser visualizada online em [Aqui](http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index5.php)

Resolvi deixar dentro do bloco com a imagem mesmo e fazer uma animação mais alta;

Mas ainda preciso de ajuda com 2 coisas:

1) Notem que, quando aparece o efeito `faide`, parece que o texto some (***tem que olhar com atenção pois não é sempre que ocorre***).

2) Não estou conseguindo compatibilizar os tempos das 3 animações para rodarem ao mesmo tempo.

Segue a resposta:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    function animaTextos(){
     var interval;
     var contador = 1;
     var funcao = function() {
      var corrente = $('div.slider ul.slide li').length;
      if(corrente == contador) {
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo');
       $('div.slider ul.slide li').first().addClass('tituloAtivo');
       contador = 1;
      } else {
       contador++;
       $('div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo').removeClass('tituloAtivo').next().addClass('tituloAtivo');
   
      }
     };
     interval = setInterval(funcao, 1000);
    }
   
    animaTextos();
   }); 


      window.onload = function() {
    
         var indexAtiva = 0;
   
         const lis = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').item(0).getElementsByTagName('li');
      
         function slider(s) {
      
            for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
               lis[i].classList.remove('ativa');
            }
      
            // aqui irá tratar o clique no "Anterior".
            // É preciso tratar de 3 formas diferentes
            // dependendo do valor de indexAtiva.
            // Veja que o valor de indexAtiva, em cada caso,
            // irá receber o valor do índice ativado
            if(s){
               // significa que o próximo a mostrar será o
               // slide de índice 1, então está sendo exibido o 0.
               // neste caso eu ativo o último da array
               if(indexAtiva == 1){
                  lis[lis.length-1].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-1;
                  
               // aqui diz que está exibindo o último,
               // logo próximo será o primeiro (índice 0).
               // Então eu ativo o antepenúltimo da array
               }else if(indexAtiva == 0){
                  lis[lis.length-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva = lis.length-2;
                  
                // aqui é quando não for nenhum dos casos anteriores.
                // Eu diminuo 2 índices porque mais a frente será
                // incrementado com +1
               }else{
                  lis[indexAtiva-2].className = 'ativa';
                  indexAtiva -= 2;
               }
            }else{
               // aqui é quando for clicado o botão "próximo"
               // ou quando nenhum botão for clicado
               lis[indexAtiva].className = 'ativa';
            }
      
            indexAtiva = indexAtiva + 1 == lis.length ? 0 : indexAtiva+=1;
      
            tempo = setTimeout(slider, 4000);
         }
      
         slider();
         
         var slider1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]
         var nav = slider1.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
         var anterior = nav.getElementsByClassName('anterior')[0]
         var proximo = nav.getElementsByClassName('proximo')[0]
         
         anterior.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider(true);
         }
         
         proximo.onclick = function(){
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            slider();
         }
      
      }
```

```css
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
          outline: 0;
      }
      body {
          width: 100vw;
      }
      ul {
          list-style: none;
      }
   .setaDireita {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/direita.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
   .setaEsquerda {
    background-image:url(_img/_bannerImgs/esquerda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
      .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
       @keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
      @keyframes slider {
       0% {
       transform: scale(1);
      }
       100% {
       transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      }
      div.slider {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide {
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li {
          display: none;
      }
      .ativa {
          display: block !important;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li img {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          animation: slider 1.5s linear, fade 1.5s linear;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li span {
          position: absolute;
          width: 500px;
          left: calc(50% - 250px);
    
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
          text-align: center;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
    
    opacity : 0;
    top : 60%;
    font-size : 4vw;
    -webkit-transition : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition : all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition : all 1s ease-in-out;
    
          z-index: 2;
      }
   
   div.slider ul.slide li.tituloAtivo span {
    text-decoration : none;
    opacity : 1;
    top : 20%;
    -webkit-transition : all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition : all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition : all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition : all 1.5s ease-in-out;
   }
   
      div.slider nav {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      div.slider nav button {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      div.slider nav button.anterior {
          left: 10%;
      }
      div.slider nav button.proximo {
          right: 10%;
      }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.js"></script>    
    <div class="slider">

      <ul class="slide">

        <li class="ativa tituloAtivo"> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 1</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 2</span> 
        </li>
        <li> 
           <img src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" /> 
           <span>Este é 3</span> 
         </li>

      </ul>

      <nav>
        <button class="anterior setaEsquerda"></button>
        <button class="proximo setaDireita"></button>
      </nav>

    </div>
```